# Fadeout with jquery.slidertron-1.1.js

Tags: html, jquery, css, slideshow

Currently i'm using [this script](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxteW91dHNvdXJjaW5nYnVzaW5lc3NtaXNzaW9uN3xneDoyYmQ0YzgzZTVmZGYxYmFi) and i kinda like it

And here's how the HTML and CSS looks like.

```html
<div id="slider">
    <div class="viewer">
        <div class="reel">
        <div class="slide"> <img src="images/IMG9.jpg" width="900" height="500" alt="" /> </div>
        <div class="slide"> <img src="images/IMG8.jpg" width="900" height="500" alt="" /> </div>
        <div class="slide"> <img src="images/IMG7.jpg" width="900" height="500" alt="" /> </div>
        <div class="slide"> <img src="images/IMG6.jpg" width="900" height="500" alt="" /> </div>
        <div class="slide"> <img src="images/IMG5.jpg" width="900" height="500" alt="" /> </div>
        <div class="slide"> <img src="images/IMG4.jpg" width="900" height="500" alt="" /> </div>
        <div class="slide"> <img src="images/IMG3.jpg" width="900" height="500" alt="" /> </div>
        <div class="slide"> <img src="images/IMG2.jpg" width="900" height="500" alt="" /> </div>
        <div class="slide"> <img src="images/IMG1.jpg" width="900" height="500" alt="" /> </div>
    </div>
</div>


#slider
{
position: relative;
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#slider .viewer
{
width: 900px;
height: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#slider .viewer .reel
{
isplay: none;
height: 500px;
}
#slider .viewer .reel .slide
{
position: relative;
width: 900px;
height: 500px;
}
```

Only problem is that i like the faded version better. So is there any easy way to change that or do i have to switch js script completely?

Comment: As a general tip: You won't get an answer on SO by writing questions like this. It is generally good to show a working example. In this case you are asking us if that component has a particular effect ([you have to read the official guide](https://www.caesoft.es/js/jquery.slidertron-1.1/docs/index.html)), if it doesn't have that effect, move on to something else.

Comment: A working example is kinda hard since i running everything local untill it works but thanks anyway.

Comment: [A working example made in 5 minutes](https://jsfiddle.net/omb8un3c/). Cheers.